# Post image on twitter using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, twitter, puppeteer

Is it possible to post an image on twitter using nodejs and puppeteer? It find it hard because when you click on the image button on twitter it opens your archive.

Comment: The closest thing I saw was using automation Python library, which interacts straight with the UI. Puppeteer does say you can: `Automate form submission, UI testing, keyboard input, etc.` so you should be able to.

Answer (score -1):

It's definetely possible to post image on Twitter automatically (using Node.js). Twitter API Client for node called 'twit' suits for it. You can find the package on [github](http://github.com/ttezel/twit) or [npm](http://npmjs.com/package/twit).

```js
// post a tweet with media

var b64content = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/img', { encoding: 'base64' })

// first we must post the media to Twitter
T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
  // now we can assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers and
  // other text-based presentations and interpreters
  var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string
  var altText = "Small flowers in a planter on a sunny balcony, blossoming."
  var meta_params = { media_id: mediaIdStr, alt_text: { text: altText } }

  T.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function (err, data, response) {
    if (!err) {
      // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
      var params = { status: 'loving life #nofilter', media_ids: [mediaIdStr] }

      T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log(data)
      })
    }
  })
})
// post media via the chunked media upload API.
// You can then use POST statuses/update to post a tweet with the media attached as in the example above using `media_id_string`.
// Note: You can also do this yourself manually using T.post() calls if you want more fine-grained
// control over the streaming. Example: https://github.com/ttezel/twit/blob/master/tests/rest_chunked_upload.js#L20
//
var filePath = '/absolute/path/to/file.mp4'
T.postMediaChunked({ file_path: filePath }, function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Please put the answer here. The video might be deleted at any point making your answer useless.

Comment: Ok, thanks for warning!
Twitter API Client for node called 'twit' suits for posting images. You can find it on github (https://github.com/ttezel/twit) or npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit).
For posting a tweet with media use this endpoint
T.post('media/upload', { media_data: name }, function (err, data, response)

Comment: You can edit your original answer to include this content. It might get lost in the comments

Comment: this doesn't use puppeteer and requires a developer account.